# Dynamically resize height of stacked divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, resize, height

On my magento homepage, I have a section where I have 3 image collages stacked on top of each other.

I'd like it so that each "collage"/div dynamically resizes its height to that of the browser you opened it in, so that as you scroll down, each one fits the window perfectly.

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(function() {
$('#universe1').height($(window).height() - 46);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
</script>
```

and make each div id'd "universe1" but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Any ideas?

Comment: i think you have to use masonary script for that

Comment: For a page each id must be unique. What do you mean by `make each div id'd "universe1"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery's .on() method to attach your event handler.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="universe">1</div>
<div class="universe">2</div>
<div class="universe">3</div>

// jQuery
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.universe').height($(window).height() - 46);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/IFEPEkaY/1/

Also make sure you're using classes as in the example above, NOT ids like in your code. If you use ids, only the first one will go full screen.  If you MUST use ids (this is ugly) the simplest thing is to do this:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="universe1">1</div>
<div id="universe2">2</div>
<div id="universe3">3</div>

// jQuery
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('#universe1').height($(window).height() - 46);
    $('#universe2').height($(window).height() - 46);
    $('#universe3').height($(window).height() - 46);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/eboXAXEq/1